# BFL - bind variables

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We're trying to use a Bayesian Filter to do some sensor fusion for estimating the joints positions on a joint based robot. For this we're using the **BFL library** as is done in the [robot-pose-ekf](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/tree/hydro-devel/robot_pose_ekf) package.

We now have two versions of the same filter (one using `ExtendedKalmanFilter`, the other one a particle filter: `BootstrapFilter`) that converges but haven't yet found a way of binding the BFL state representation variables. In our case, we'd like to make sure that each variable of the state stays within the joint limits.

Feel free to ask for more details as I'm not exactly sure what is most relevant.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189700/bfl---bind-variables/) by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1620 on 2014-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*from Enrico on BFL mailing list*

This is a constrained optimization problem. I am afraid there is no "clean" way of doing this.
If the state variables are defined by Gaussian pdfs, than by definition
those span an infinite support.

You could try to make variables outside of the joint limits "highly
unlikely" by filtering your measurements, and rejecting those outside a
validation area, or carefully defining Process noise and Measurement Noise
Covariance Matrices, but if you really want to use  constraints, that
you're actually solving an Estimation + Constrained Optimization problem,
and you'll need different tools for that.

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2014-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0